# Java - how to use char array in switch statement?

Tags: java, arrays

Can a character array be used in switch statement as shown below? When I tried that, it shows an error that char cannot be converted to int, i.e. incompatible types.

```
char[] valuetoo = { 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e'};

switch (valuetoo){
    case 'a':
        System.out.println("the character found is 'a'");
        break;
    case 'b':
        System.out.println("the character found is 'b'");
        break;
    case 'c':
    case 'd':
    case 'e':
        System.out.println("the character found is ");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("the characters are not found");
}
```

The error is:

```
Error:(39, 16) java: incompatible types: char[] cannot be converted to int
```

Comment: this doesn't make sense... you have to compare something to each case, and an array can't equal 'a'. you probably mean to run this code once for each letter in the array, in which case you should use a loop.

Comment: You could switch on `valuetoo[0]`, if you liked.  Or any index.  You can't switch on the whole array at once.

Comment: The error message says you can't. So you can't. NB It doesn't say what you claimed: it says '`char[]` cannot be converted to `int`'. Not `char`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You provide a char array in the `switch` clause. You cannot.

[The Java language(14.11. The switch Statement)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-SwitchStatement) allows only these types as expression of the switch statement:

> The type of the *Expression* must be `char, byte, short, int, Character,
>   Byte, Short, Integer, String,` or an `enum` type (§8.9), or a
>   compile-time error occurs.

You should provide the actual `char` for which you want to apply the `switch-case` statement. 
Now, if you want to do apply the `switch-case` statement for all elements of an array of char, you can loop over the `switch` with the elements of the array :

```
char[] valuetoo = { 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e'};      
for (char c : valuetoo){
     switch (c){
        case 'a':
            System.out.println("the character found is 'a'");
            break;
        case 'b':
            System.out.println("the character found is 'b'");
            break;
        case 'c':case 'd':case 'e':
            System.out.println("the character found is ");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("the characters are not found");
      }
  }
```

Comment: can i use integer or other data types  with array in switch statement? thanks for help! @davidxxx

Comment: @mamidi.bunty What part of 'The type of the *Expression* must be `char, byte, short, int, Character, Byte, Short, Integer, String,` or an `enum` type' didn't you understand?

Comment: when i checked about, how to use char with switch statement in oracle website,there was an array for char type.so i was curious if char array can be used with switch statement as shown in above code.@EJP

Comment: @mamidi.bunty But there wasn't code like yours. You need to read what the error message actually says. Not what you think it says. Ditto the JLS. Ditto the Oracle website.

Answer (score 0):

You Cannot Pass Array Name to a Switch Case But you can pass Array index to itas below

```
 switch (valuetoo[0]){
        //body here
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

You should not use char array inside switch

Better add `switch(valuetoo[index])`

Comment: `char` array will *not* convert into `int`. Read the error message.